# Paramiko script and "RPC: Remote system error"

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, mount, nfs

I'm writing a Python script which lets local Ubuntu machine connecting to a remote linux machine(on the same local network) by Paramiko, and then uses `exec_command()` to execute `mount -t nfs -o tcp,nolock <local machine ip>:/path/to/local/directory /path/to/remote/directory` command.

However, when I run my script, it will hang at the mount command for a while, and `stderr` return by `exec_command()` shows the following error:

```
mount: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
mount: mounting <local machine ip>:/path/to/local/directory on /path/to/remote/directory failed: Bad file descriptor
```

I've googled for several possibilities and they are all checked:

1. my `/etc/exports` includes the remote machine's address, in which I add the line: 
   `/path/to/local/directory 192.168.2.0/24(rw,nohide,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)`
2. when normally `ssh` to the remote machine, I can use the same command to mount the local directory on the remote machine.
3. `rpcinfo -p` shows portmapper and nfs running normally

I also log in to the remote machine, and use `ps` to check if the command is received correctly:

```
 1894 root      1380 S    sh -c mount -t nfs -o tcp,nolock ...
 1895 root      1376 S    mount -t nfs -o tcp,nolock ...
 1901 root      1372 S    sleep 180
 1902 root      1376 R    ps
```

Finally, following is my code:

```
def executeCMD(sshC, setupCMD, hostCMD, scpCMD, cleanCMD):
    confirm = ''
    for cmd in setupCMD:
        if cmd.startswith('rm -r'):
            while confirm not in ['y', 'n']:
                confirm = (
                           input('Command to execute: "{}" Are you sure?(y/n) '.format(cmd))
                                .strip()
                                .lower()
                          )
            if confirm == 'y':
                stdin, stdout, stderr = sshC.exec_command(cmd)
                logger.info('{} (Recv: {})'.format(cmd,
                                                   stderr.read().decode()))
                for cmd in hostCMD:
                    cmdOut = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                              shell=True)
                    out = cmdOut.stdout.read().decode()
                    logger.info('{}'.format(out))
                for cmd in scpCMD:
                    scpC = SCPClient(sshC.get_transport())
                    scpC.put(*cmd)
            elif confirm == 'n':
                for cmd in cleanCMD:
                    stdin, stdout, stderr = sshC.exec_command(cmd)
                    logger.info('{} (Recv: {})'.format(cmd,
                                                       stderr.read().decode()))
                return 1
        else:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = sshC.exec_command(cmd)
            logger.info('{} (Recv: {})'.format(cmd,
                                               stderr.read().decode()))
    return 0
```

I'm wondering if anyone has the same problem?

Comment: *＋1* for asking an SSH question that has to do with programming and development.

Comment: trying to use `subprocess` and `sshpass -p <password> ssh <user@address> <mount command>` as a workaround, but it still shows the same error. I'm getting more confused...

Comment: OK, I managed to get it work by retrying `subprocess` + `sshpass -p ...` several times. The strange thing is that it only fails the first time, and you only need to retry for one time to get it work. But it is so annoying to wait the first faiilure for 2 minutes, so I think I will do more research on it.